# What is right syntax for my foreign key?

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> create table dispatch(
          booking_no int
         ,bdate date
         ,src_stn varchar(20)
         ,dest_stn varchar(20)
         ,consignee varchar(30)
         ,desc_goods varchar(40)
         ,no_of_art smallint
         ,total float
         ,driver_name varchar(30)
         ,lorry_no varchar(10)
         ,status varchar(5)
         ,primary key (booking_no)
         ,foreign key(booking_no,bdate,src_stn,dest_stn,consignee,desc_goods,no_of_art,total) references booking(booking_no,bdate,src_stn,dest_stn,consignee,desc_goods,no_of_art,total));
```

> ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: "What is right syntax for my foreign key?" We can't say without the table booking bust normally you would include indexed columns only within foreign keys... The best is to look into the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html for it's syntax

Comment: There is no evidence here of a syntax problem. Have you considered looking up MySQL error 1215?

Answer (score -1):

Try This :-

First Create Two normal table with primary key CONSTRAINT

Then After,

ALTER TABLE dispatch ADD FOREIGN KEY (booking_no) REFERENCES booking(booking_no);